# Usage / Top Build Pipelines report has no data

Tags: report

Can't wrap my head around, why it shows no data?

Several build pipelines are running now and then, the latest run happened just today several hour ago, but the report with no filters has no data at all.

Comment: Could you please provide more details regards your question and the problem you're facing. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

It's totally counter-intuitive, but if the filter was initially on "Last hour" (which is the default), if you click on "Click and dismiss filters" and "Refresh", then it's the filter **bar** who gets dismissed, not the **active filter** itself.

At least, the report will still be filtered by the "Last hour" filter